# How to solve $(x')^2+4x-4tx'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$-\frac 14(\dfrac {dx}{dt})^2 - x(t) + t \dfrac {dx}{dt} =0 $$
I tried to substitute: $p= dx/dt$. 
result:$ dx/dy = p=2t  \pm \sqrt x$ , but solving this equation is very complicate and the solution is not "pretty".
Wolfralpha shows "pretty" solution [Wolfram  Alpha ' solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%281%2F4%29%28x%27%28t%29%29%5E2%20-%20x%28t%29%20%2B%20tx%27%28t%29%3D0)

Comment: Your question is VERY messy. There are many tips that show up when you ask a question about how to format, and it's clear you've read none of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-\frac 14(\dfrac {dx}{dt})^2 - x(t) + t \dfrac {dx}{dt} =0$$
$$x(t)= t \dfrac {dx}{dt}-\frac 14(\dfrac {dx}{dt})^2    $$
This is [Clairaut's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation). It's of the form :
$$x(t)=tx'+g(x')$$
Differentiate:
$$x(t)= t \dfrac {dx}{dt}-\frac 14(\dfrac {dx}{dt})^2    $$
$$t x''-\frac 12x'x'' =0   $$
$$ x''(t-\frac 12x') =0   $$
For the general solution we have:
$$x''=0  \implies x'=C$$
$$x(t)= Ct-\frac 14C^2    $$
For the singular solution of Clairaut's differential equation we have:
$$x'(t)=2t $$
This DE is easy to solve.
$$x=t^2+C_1$$
Plug this in the DE you get $C_1=0$
$$\implies x(t)=t^2$$

Comment: thank you! Now i know how i can solve this kind of equation.

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach to Clairaut's equation is as follows.

> Taking derivatives with respect to $t$ gives $$-\frac12x'x''-x'+x'+tx''=0,$$ that is, $$-\frac12x'x''+tx''=0.$$
>   So either $x''=0$ or $x'=2t$. Both equations are easy to solve.